# Why do isolation levels REPEATABLE_READ and SERIALIZABLE in Springboot Transaction allow concurrent read instead of sequential read?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, transactions

I am trying to understand how transaction isolation levels work in general. Hence I have created a simple Springboot application with MySQL as the DB that basically increments the value of a particular row in the DB by 1 every time an API is called.

I have the following `TestEntity` class

```
@Entity(name = "test")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String ipAddress;

    private Long value;
}
```

And I have the following API that allows the communication with the DB

```
@GetMapping("db")
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public void testDb(final HttpServletRequest request) {
  final String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-Real-IP");
  log.debug("Received IP: {}", ipAddress);
  final var testEntityOptional = testRepository.findByIpAddress(ipAddress);
  testEntityOptional.ifPresent((testEntity -> {
    log.debug("Retrieved Test Entity: {}", testEntity);
    testEntity.setValue(testEntity.getValue() + 1);
  }));
}
```

You can notice that I have set the isolation level as **REPEATABLE_READ**.

Initial state of DB:

```
id|ip_address|value|
--+----------+-----+
30|1.0.0.2   |    1|
```

When I hit this API with 5 concurrent requests using Apache JMeter, I get the following output in the console:

```
2021-09-25 14:11:48.021 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-3] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:11:48.021 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-4] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:11:48.021 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:11:48.021 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-2] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:11:48.021 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:11:48.024 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-4] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:11:48.024 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-3] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:11:48.024 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:11:48.024 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:11:48.024 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-2] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
```

Below is the DB state after the request:

```
id|ip_address|value|
--+----------+-----+
30|1.0.0.2   |    2|
```

You can see that the value updated to 2 instead of 6 (5+1)

When I run it with isolation level **SERIALIZABLE**, I get the following output

```
2021-09-25 14:17:12.227 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:17:12.227 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-9] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:17:12.227 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:17:12.227 DEBUG 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:17:12.228 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:17:12.228 DEBUG 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:17:12.228 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-1] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:17:12.228 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-9] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=1)
2021-09-25 14:17:12.229  WARN 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
2021-09-25 14:17:12.229 ERROR 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
2021-09-25 14:17:12.230 ERROR 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at ........................

2021-09-25 14:17:12.227 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Received IP: 1.0.0.2
2021-09-25 14:17:12.229  WARN 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
2021-09-25 14:17:12.229  WARN 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
2021-09-25 14:17:12.231 ERROR 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
2021-09-25 14:17:12.231 ERROR 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
2021-09-25 14:17:12.232 ERROR 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at ........................

2021-09-25 14:17:12.232 ERROR 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at ........................

2021-09-25 14:17:12.250 DEBUG 25981 --- [nio-8001-exec-8] i.t.t.a.controllers.TestController       : Retrieved Test Entity: TestEntity(id=30, ipAddress=1.0.0.2, value=2)
```

And the DB state changes from

```
id|ip_address|value|
--+----------+-----+
30|1.0.0.2   |    1|
```

to

```
id|ip_address|value|
--+----------+-----+
30|1.0.0.2   |    3|
```

When I check in the DB, I see the value as 3, meaning two out of the 5 threads were able to read the updated values and then increment properly.

Correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I know, both `REPEATABLE_READ` and `SERLIAZABLE` put a **read-lock** on all the rows/table to be read and **write-lock** on all the rows that are being modified.

If this understanding is correct, then how come in case of `REPEATABLE_READ`, all 5 of the threads read the same data? Shouldn't the read-lock have prevented other 4 threads from even reading the DB? Should not the read have been in a sequential fashion where only after one thread was done reading / writing would the other thread be able to access it?

And why, in case of `SERIALIZABLE`, were two threads able to execute the expected behavior, that is be able to read the updated value and then increment, and the other 3 weren't? It seems to me that the serializable read that I was expecting in REPEATABLE_READ is happening here, but only partially

What am I missing here?

Thanks for taking the time to read

Comment: About SERIALIZABLE lvl, when you are getting data in one transaction you can't change them in the same transaction. But you are trying to do it. Each of your threads will do a "read-modify-write" operation, there are will be a deadlock for a random run.

Comment: @DmitriiBykov 
Could you please explain "when you are getting data in one transaction you can't change them in the same transaction"?
I always thought SERIALIZABLE locked the entire row so that no other transactions could read / modify it. And if one transaction has the lock on it, why should it not be allowed to do whatever it wants with it?
I have seen that when I run an update statement on the row before I read it (and then update again), all the threads read data sequentially. As in T1 reads 1 and updates to 2, then T2 reads 2 and updates to 3 and so on. 
Is it because of write-lock?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database engine being used. I guess you are using InnoDB since that is the default storage engine for MySQL.

Traditional lock based database they work on locks on rows, pages and they can eventually even escalate to full blown table locks.

But most modern databases (like InnoDB) make use of Multi Version Concurrency Control and readers and writes can happen concurrently. So imagine the following 2 entries in some table:

```
X=1
Y=1
```

And there are 2 transactions A and B using Serializable isolation level. And transaction A has read X=1 and transaction B comes in and increments Y, it will lock row Y until it commits. When transaction A wants to read Y, it doesn't care about the newly updated version of Y (and can ignore the lock). It can reconstruct the value of Y=1 using the undo/redo logs.

The idea is that only writers will block other writers but they will not block readers. Tom Kyte wrote some excellent books about Oracle and MVCC.

Answer to your question:

In the logs you can see:

```
2021-09-25 14:17:12.230 ERROR 25981 --- [io-8001-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at ........................
```

So my understanding is that one transaction was able to read the value for some record. A different transaction comes in an updates the record. When the first transaction wants to write, it sees that the version it has read is older than the current committed version. And as a consequence won't acquire the lock.

So something along these lines:

```
Transaction 1: start
Transaction 1: read record (value 1) and version 1.
Transaction 2: start
Transaction 2: read record (value 1) and version 1
Transaction 2: lock record with version 1
Transaction 2: write value=2 to record.
Transaction 2: commit: increment the record to version 2
Transaction 2: lock record with version 1  <----- boom
```

These versions are tracked by the MVCC database engine. The information is added to each row.

If you would trigger a 'select for update' instead of a regular 'select', this problem would be prevented because then the select would lead to a lock of the record and you would not run into this optimistic locking failure.

PS: I haven't worked with regular databases for a very long time. So my knowledge could be a bit shaky.